# Hide Facebook like button after it is clicked

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-like

I need to hide the Facebook like button on my site when is clicked. I use the official like button for my fanpage. When a visitor clicks like and becomes a fan, I want the like button to disappear and be hidden from him forever. I found that it can be done with `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create;)` but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy:

1) Place the like button within a container.
2) Subscribe to FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create'). 
3) When user has liked, hide the container.

Comment: Sounds easy but i have no idea how to do that :D...Can you please write the code for that...i don't know javascript coding...Thank you!